# mysql-server not installing on ubuntu

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu

I had a problem in mysql login so i tried to reinstall mysql-server But I am unable to reinstall

*Ubuntu Version 13.04

I tried following command

```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install  mysql-server
   sudo service mysql restart
```

but it gives following errors

```
root@bts23:~# sudo apt-get install mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libaio1 libdbd-mysql-perl libdbi-perl libmysqlclient18 libnet-daemon-perl libplrpc-perl libterm-readkey-perl mysql-client-5.5 mysql-client-core-5.5
  mysql-common mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server-core-5.5
Suggested packages:
  tinyca mailx
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libaio1 libdbd-mysql-perl libdbi-perl libmysqlclient18 libnet-daemon-perl libplrpc-perl libterm-readkey-perl mysql-client-5.5 mysql-client-core-5.5
  mysql-common mysql-server mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server-core-5.5
0 upgraded, 13 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 26.1 MB/26.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 91.3 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y


WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  libaio1 mysql-common libmysqlclient18 libnet-daemon-perl libplrpc-perl libdbi-perl libdbd-mysql-perl mysql-client-core-5.5 libterm-readkey-perl
  mysql-client-5.5 mysql-server-core-5.5 mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server
Install these packages without verification [y/N]? y
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main libaio1 i386 0.3.109-3
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main mysql-common all 5.5.29-0ubuntu1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main libmysqlclient18 i386 5.5.29-0ubuntu1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main libdbi-perl i386 1.622-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main libdbd-mysql-perl i386 4.021-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main mysql-client-core-5.5 i386 5.5.29-0ubuntu1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main mysql-client-5.5 i386 5.5.29-0ubuntu1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main mysql-server-core-5.5 i386 5.5.29-0ubuntu1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main mysql-server-5.5 i386 5.5.29-0ubuntu1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main mysql-server all 5.5.29-0ubuntu1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/liba/libaio/libaio1_0.3.109-3_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mysql-5.5/mysql-common_5.5.29-0ubuntu1_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mysql-5.5/libmysqlclient18_5.5.29-0ubuntu1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libd/libdbi-perl/libdbi-perl_1.622-1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libd/libdbd-mysql-perl/libdbd-mysql-perl_4.021-1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mysql-5.5/mysql-client-core-5.5_5.5.29-0ubuntu1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mysql-5.5/mysql-client-5.5_5.5.29-0ubuntu1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mysql-5.5/mysql-server-core-5.5_5.5.29-0ubuntu1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mysql-5.5/mysql-server-5.5_5.5.29-0ubuntu1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mysql-5.5/mysql-server_5.5.29-0ubuntu1_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

and when I try to restart/status after this it throw following error

```
root@bts23:~# service mysql restart
mysql: unrecognized service
root@bts23:~# mysql
The program 'mysql' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
apt-get install mysql-client-core-5.5
root@bts23:~#
```

Comment: Check http://askubuntu.com

Comment: Please wait for few time. It seems the download server is currently unavailable.

Comment: [DJ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3466544/dj-mha) i am doing this since morning But its throwing same error every time.

Comment: @SunilKumar you should update os by using `sudo apt-get update` then try again

Comment: can you tell me why someone downvoted it because i am trying to fix this problem since morning and i am unable to do anything, So i came here. And seems like the person who downvoted it must know the solution, so can you share it plz ?

Comment: [DJ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3466544/dj-mha) when i am trying this its giving same error eg Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

Comment: @SunilKumar You can install mysql using `rpm` client, server, community.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a look here `http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/` you can see there is no `raring` folder. This is why you get a 404 error.

Support for Ubuntu 13.04 officially ended on January 27, 2014. If you still want to use this release try to update your sources files(/etc/apt/sources.list) with `http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/`

Comment: [demostene](http://stackoverflow.com/users/500514/demostene) so it will be possible only after upgrading my OS to latest version.

Comment: Try updating the /etc/apt/sources.list first.

Answer (score 0):

Change the **Download from** Server to **Main Serve**r in **Software and Update** Settings.Then follow these commands to remove the mysql server(if presents) completely and install it again..

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common mysql-server-5.5 mysql-client-5.5 mysql-server-core-5.5 mysql-client-core-5.5
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql /etc/mysql
sudo deluser mysql
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo reboot
sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.6
```